# How can I declare a new variable of the same class but with different template parameters in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a template function that, given any class, will instantiate a new one but the template param is 1.  I would like to do something like this:

```cpp
template <uint COUNT>
class Foo {
    using MY_NAME = Foo;
    int data[COUNT];
    void print();
}

template <class T>
void my_function(T in) {
    auto x = in::MY_NAME<1>;  // This somehow makes a XXX<whatever> into an XXX<1>.
    x.print();
}

my_function(Foo<5>); // This should call Foo<1>.print();
```

I want to use templates or `using` or something so that whatever input class I'm receiving, I make a new instance that is the same class but with a different template parameter.

Can this be done?  It's all known at compile time so it seems like there ought to be a way to do it.

Comment: `in::MY_NAME<1>;` what's this? `in` is an instance not the class

Comment: IMO crucial details are missing and as a result you will get  overcomplicated answer to something what is probably quite easy. Please provide a details what are requirements for `T` how `Foo` should look like and anything else what could help fully understand your problem. I would not be surprise if simple dependent typ could do this job.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter).  In this case, you would want to specify a non-type template parameter for the inner tempalte.  That would look like

```
template <std::size_t COUNT>
struct Foo {
    using MY_NAME = Foo;
    int data[COUNT];
    void print() { std::cout << "COUNT: " << COUNT; }
};

template <template<std::size_t> typename class_t, std::size_t N>
void my_function(class_t<N>) {
    auto x = class_t<1>{};  // This somehow makes a XXX<whatever> into an XXX<1>.
    x.print();
}

int main()
{
    my_function(Foo<5>{}); // This should call Foo<1>.print();
}
```

and it outputs

```
COUNT: 1
```

as seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74fd0cda18caf2b4).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's possible to make the using declaration do what you want it to, making `MY_NAME` refer to the injected template name `Foo` instead of the injected class name `Foo<COUNT>`. However you can make `MY_NAME` be itself a template:

```
#include <iostream>

template <uint COUNT>
class Foo {
public:
    template<uint C>
    using MY_NAME = Foo<C>;
    
    int data[COUNT];
    void print() { std::cout << COUNT << '\n'; }
};

template <class T>
void my_function(T in) {
    auto x = typename T::MY_NAME<1>{};  // Typename keyword is necessary here
    x.print();
}

int main()
{
    my_function(Foo<5>{}); // Prints 1
    my_function(Foo<7>{}); // Prints 1
}
```

Demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ja6YM6qG8).

So now for any class template `Bar` that exports its name via `using MY_NAME` you can pass it to `my_function` to call `Bar<1>.print()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need it for but the syntax you're looking could be this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t N>
struct Foo
{
    // initialized array
    std::array<int,N> data {};

    // output all the values in the array
    void print()
    {
        for (const int value : data) std::cout << value << " ";
    }
};

template<typename type_t>
void my_function(const type_t& value)
{
    std::cout << "my_function(" << value << ")\n";
    // create a temporary and print it.
    Foo<1>().print();
}

int main()
{
    int v{ 5 };
    my_function<int>(v);
}
```